# How to make timer circle to run according to timer entries

Tags: javascript, angular, timer

I have a timer, which is bounded with a circle. The circle also moves along with the running entries with the timer. If i play circle it move according to seconds, if i pause the circle also gets paused and stop means it goes back to zero. But now if i run the timer and change page, the timer circle will go forward and backward. It is not running according to number of seconds at present.It is taking two entries i am not getting from where issue is arising. Please help
I am hereby sharing my codes please help:

**HTML Code**:

```
<round-progress [current]="current" [max]="3600" [stroke]="6" [radius]="100" [rounded]="false" [responsive]="false" [color]="color" [background]="background" [duration]="800" [animation]="animation"></round-progress>
```

**track.ts**

```
                this.ApiService
                    .runningEntries(this.user_id)
                    .subscribe(
                      entries  => {
                       if(entries.current) {
                         this.currentTask = entries.current;
                         var miliSecond = entries.current.ms;
                         var second = parseInt(miliSecond) / 1000;
                         this.current = parseInt(second.toFixed(2))
                         if(this.current < 0)
                          {
                          this.current = 0;
                          }
                         this.playPauseStopUnsubscribe.unsubscribe();
                         var last = entries.current.times[entries.current.times.length - 1];
                         if((last.state == 'start') || (last.state == 'resume')) {
                           this.play = true;
                         } else if(last.state == 'pause') {
                           this.play = false;
                         }
                       }
                    }
```

**time.ts**

```
this.ApiService
        .checklogin()
        .subscribe(
          user  => {
            /*Get Running Entries */  
            this.ApiService
                .runningEntries(user.user._id)
                .subscribe(
                    entries  => {
                     if(entries.current) {
                        var miliSecond = entries.current.ms;
                        var second = parseInt(miliSecond) / 1000;
                        second = parseInt(second.toFixed(2))
                        this.start = second;
                        var length = entries.current.times.length;
                        var last_entry = entries.current.times[length - 1];
                        if((last_entry.state == 'start') || (last_entry.state == 'resume')) {
                           this.startTimer();
                        } else if(last_entry.state == 'pause') {
                           this.pauseInitTimer();

                        }
                     }
                 }, error =>{
                    //console.log(error);
                 });
```